# Will python SystemRandom / os.urandom always have enough entropy for good crypto

Tags: python, linux, random, cryptography, generator

I have a password generator:

```
import random, string

def gen_pass():
    foo = random.SystemRandom()
    length = 64
    chars = string.letters + string.digits
    return ''.join(foo.choice(chars) for _ in xrange(length))
```

According to the docs, `SystemRandom` uses `os.urandom` which uses `/dev/urandom` to throw out random crypto bits. In Linux you can get random bits from `/dev/urandom` or `/dev/random`, they both use whatever entropy the kernel can get its hands on. The amount of entropy available can be checked with `tail /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail`, this will return a number like: 129. The higher the number, the more entropy is available. The difference between `/dev/urandom` and `/dev/random` is that `/dev/random` will only spit out bits if `entropy_avail` is high enough (like at least 60) and `/dev/urandom` will always spit out bits. The docs say that `/dev/urandom` is good for crypto and you only have to use `/dev/random` for ssl certs and the like.

My question is will `gen_pass` be good for making strong crypto grade passwords always? If I call this function as quickly as possible will I stop getting strong crypto bits at some point because the entropy pool is depleted?

The question could also be why does `/dev/urandom` *always* produce strong crypto bits *and* not care about the `entropy_avail`?

It is possible that `/dev/urandom` is designed so that its bandwidth is capped by the number of cycles you can guess will be correlated with an amount of entropy, but this is speculation and I can't find an answer.

Also this is my first stackoverflow question so please critique me. I am concerned that I gave to much background when someone who knows the answer probably knows the background.

Thanks

**update**

I wrote some code to look at the entropy pool while the `/dev/urandom` was being read from:

```
import subprocess
import time

from pygooglechart import Chart
from pygooglechart import SimpleLineChart
from pygooglechart import Axis

def check_entropy():
    arg = ['cat', '/proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail']
    ps = subprocess.Popen(arg,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    return int(ps.communicate()[0])

def run(number_of_tests,resolution,entropy = []):
    i = 0
    while i < number_of_tests:        
        time.sleep(resolution)
        entropy += [check_entropy()]
        i += 1
    graph(entropy,int(number_of_tests*resolution))

def graph(entropy,rng):    
    max_y = 200    
    chart = SimpleLineChart(600, 375, y_range=[0, max_y])
    chart.add_data(entropy)
    chart.set_colours(['0000FF'])
    left_axis = range(0, max_y + 1, 32)
    left_axis[0] = 'entropy'
    chart.set_axis_labels(Axis.LEFT, left_axis)    
    chart.set_axis_labels(Axis.BOTTOM,['time in second']+get_x_axis(rng))
    chart.download('line-stripes.png')

def get_x_axis(rng):
    global modnum        
    if len(filter(lambda x:x%modnum == 0,range(rng + 1)[1:])) > 10:
        modnum += 1
        return get_x_axis(rng)
    return filter(lambda x:x%modnum == 0,range(rng + 1)[1:])

modnum = 1
run(500,.1)
```

If run this and also run:

```
while 1 > 0:
    gen_pass()
```

Then I pretty reliablly get a graph that looks like this:
[image]

Making the graph while running `cat /dev/urandom` looks smiler and `cat /dev/random` drops off to nothing and stays low very quickly (this also only reads out like a byte every 3 seconds or so)

**update**

If I run the same test but with six instances of gen_pass(), I get this:
[image]

So it looks like something is making it be the case that I have enough entropy. I should measure the password generation rate and make sure that it is actually being capped, because if it is not then something fishy may be going on.

**update**

I found this [email chain](https://lists.openwall.net/linux-kernel/2007/12/04/257)

This says that `urandom` will stop pulling entropy once the pool only has 128 bits in it. This is very consistent with the above results and means that in those tests I am producing junk passwords often.

My assumption before was that if the `entropy_avail` was high enough (say above 64 bits) then `/dev/urandom` output was good. This is not the case it seems that `/dev/urandom` was designed to leave extra entropy for `/dev/random` in case it needs it.

Now I need to find out how many true random bits a `SystemRandom` call needs.

Comment: Naturally it's possible - you can draw an indefinite amount of information from /dev/urandom, and you don't have an indefinite amount of entropy.

Comment: Like I said above, I think you could design is so that it is not possible, but I have no reason the believe this. I need to do more research.

Comment: @Chris How? The entropy has to come from somewhere - you can't just magic it up. If you could, our lives would be a lot easier.

Comment: If you assume a average rate of entropy generation, and then you force the `/dev/urandom` process to take a certain amount of time (say by doing a bunch of hashes) then you could more or less force it to be the case that there is enough entropy by computationally limiting the bandwidth of reading out `/dev/urandom`. This requires the kernel being aware how quickly it generally generated entropy and throttling the bandwidth dynamically, or using some lower bound assumption for entropy generation.

Comment: However, these docs seem to confirm that nothing like that is going on [link](http://linux.die.net/man/4/random), and if you read to fast then your screwed. That being said I haven't been able to get the entropy_avail to drop below about 120 while reading from `/dev/urandom`

Comment: @Chris The point of urandom is to return as much data as is needed - `/dev/random` exists  if you need guaranteed entropy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a subtle difference between the output of `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom`.  As has been pointed out, `/dev/urandom` doesn't block.  That's because it gets its output from a pseudo-random number generator, seeded from the 'real' random numbers in `/dev/random`.

The output of `/dev/urandom` will almost always be sufficiently random -- it's a high-quality PRNG with a random seed.  If you really need a better source of random data, you could consider getting a system with a hardware random number generator -- my netbook has a [VIA C7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VIA_C7) in it, which can generate quite a lot of properly random data (I get a consistent 99.9kb/s out of `/dev/random`, 545kb/s out of `/dev/urandom`).

As an aside, if you're generating passwords then you might want to look at [`pwgen`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pwgen/) -- it makes nice pronounceable passwords for you :).

Comment: Rite, I think I've proven to myself that this will work well, but to be safe hardware is the way to go. Now I just need to figure out how to hook my geiger counter up to a serial port...

Comment: [This answer is incorrect](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key), both `random` and `urandom` retrieve their values from a PRNG. `random` blocks when there is too little entropy in the entropy pool, however entropy is stored and re-loaded when you reboot your machine, so it virtually never runs low. The only time `urandom` could give "low entropy PRNG values" is if you have freshly installed your machine and immediately read from `/dev/urandom`.

Answer (score 2):

`/dev/random/` will block on read if it needs more entropy. `/dev/urandom/` won't. So yes, if you use it too fast you'll run low on entropy. Probably still quite hard to guess, of course, but if you're really concerned you can read bytes from `/dev/random/` instead. Ideally, with a non-blocking read loop and a progress indicator so you can move the mouse around and generate entropy if needed.

Comment: `/dev/random` actually seems to give you the bits directly from the entropy pool, and from the experiments the entropy is depleted very quickly. If it is possible for `/dev/urandom` to fail I would like to know more about how it does and if you can prevent it. If you run `cat /dev/urandom` and spew crap to standard IO and also check the entropy_avail periodically there does not seem to be a problem with the entropy_avail ever. It makes me wonder if the kernel is using the process of printing `/dev/urandom/` to make more entropy, I also wonder if that is acceptable.

Comment: My recollection is that they take it from the same place, but `random` keeps track of how much entropy is available and blocks when it needs more. I would suppose that `urandom` also updates the entropy status, since someone might draw on `random` at any time. How are you checking entropy_avail? Anyway, I'd say using `urandom` and passing it through a secure hash function would be secure enough for almost any application.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to read this about why /dev/urandom is the way to go:

http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/