# Any Python password-generators that are readable and pronounceable?

Tags: python, passwords

It's simple enough to generate a random string in Python (such as [Python entropy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480131/will-python-systemrandom-os-urandom-always-have-enough-entropy-for-good-crypto) shows). But are there any Python projects out there, which will generate password strings that are both *somewhat* pronounceable and readable? By readable, I mean not putting both zeros and O's in the same string, etc. I don't care if it's got *maximum* entropy, just something better than what I'm likely to pick. :)

Comment: BTW, you might find [this](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Automated-Curse-Generator.aspx) relevant :)..

Comment: @MAK, cute - it's sort of like building a second AI to chase down a rogue AI... :) (and coincidentally, the Fukushima nuclear reactor is all the news).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're really just looking for something "better than I can make up" and
"pronounceable," then maybe just use `random.sample()` to pull from a list of 
consonant-vowel-consonant pseudosyllables:

```
import string
import itertools
import random

initial_consonants = (set(string.ascii_lowercase) - set('aeiou')
                      # remove those easily confused with others
                      - set('qxc')
                      # add some crunchy clusters
                      | set(['bl', 'br', 'cl', 'cr', 'dr', 'fl',
                             'fr', 'gl', 'gr', 'pl', 'pr', 'sk',
                             'sl', 'sm', 'sn', 'sp', 'st', 'str',
                             'sw', 'tr'])
                      )

final_consonants = (set(string.ascii_lowercase) - set('aeiou')
                    # confusable
                    - set('qxcsj')
                    # crunchy clusters
                    | set(['ct', 'ft', 'mp', 'nd', 'ng', 'nk', 'nt',
                           'pt', 'sk', 'sp', 'ss', 'st'])
                    )

vowels = 'aeiou' # we'll keep this simple

# each syllable is consonant-vowel-consonant "pronounceable"
syllables = map(''.join, itertools.product(initial_consonants, 
                                           vowels, 
                                           final_consonants))

# you could trow in number combinations, maybe capitalized versions... 

def gibberish(wordcount, wordlist=syllables):
    return ' '.join(random.sample(wordlist, wordcount))
```

Then you just choose a suitably large number of "words":

```
>>> len(syllables)
5320
>>> gibberish(4)
'nong fromp glosk zunt'
>>> gibberish(5)
'samp nuv fog blew grig'
>>> gibberish(10)
'strot fray hag sting skask stim grun prug spaf mond'
```

My statistics are a little fuzzy, but this may be enough for non-NSA 
purposes. Note that `random.sample()` operates without replacement. I should also point out that if a malicious party was aware you were using this method, it would be vulnerable to a dictionary attack. A pinch of [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) would help with that.

*Update*: For those interested, an updated and fork-able version of this is available at https://github.com/greghaskins/gibberish.

Comment: This is something like the algorithm I used back in ~1995 to generate random passwords for trial accounts on an online service. Except I wrote that in Applesoft BASIC. :-) My algorithm would occasionally slip an `h` in before or after the vowel for added exhoticness.

Comment: @kindall +1 "exhoticness". Perhaps I'll add `oy`, `ji`, `ch`, `ee`, `zz`, `fj`, and `tz` for a little multicultural flavor =)

Comment: One other thing I'll note ... you've gotta be careful that this thing doesn't produce profanity. I had a step in my program that would throw out a pseudo-word if it contained certain naughty substrings. You have done well by not including "ck" as a terminal cluster, but I think your code could still produce some very vulgar words. Hm, maybe not though... you did also eliminate "c" from the first position.

Comment: Good point. Don't want anyone to overhear you whispering certain choice words as you key in that passphrase.

Comment: Want some *[bheer](http://mrbilll.users.sonic.net/Costuming/faqs/vocab.html)* to go with your exhoticness?

Comment: I get the following when executing this code `TypeError: Population must be a sequence or set.  For dicts, use list(d).
`

Answer (score 4):

I'm a big fan of the [xkcd password generator](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xkcdpass/). Very customizable, pip installable, and the "acrostic" feature provides a nice way to give users a memory clue for their generated word set.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a simple [Markov text generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Markov_text_generators) and then train it with a list of common/pronounceable words.

Some time ago I wrote a simple generator for fun. Here it is:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

from cStringIO import StringIO
from sys import argv
import random

USAGE="usage: ./markov.py input_file"
END_TAG='<end>'
SEPARATOR='\n'

def append(model,token, target):
    if token not in model:
        model[token]=[]
    model[token].append(target)

def add_to_model(model,word, end_tag=END_TAG):
    append(model,'',word[:2])
    for i in xrange(len(word)-2):
        append(model, word[i:i+2],word[i+2])
    append(model,word[-2:],end_tag)

def generate(model, end_tag=END_TAG):
    ret=''
    while True:
        cur=random.choice(model[ret[-2:]])
        if cur==end_tag:
            break
        else:
            ret+=cur
    return ret

if __name__=='__main__':
    if len(argv)>1:
        data=file(argv[1],'r').read().split(SEPARATOR)
        model={}
        for word in data:
            add_to_model(model,word)
        print generate(model)
    else:
        print USAGE
```

Comment: Looks interesting - how much entropy would it generate? I presume it's based on the input file, so if I had lots of numbers and symbols in the text file, it would be stronger. But then, how do you avoid things like a zero and '0' together, or 1/l? Or is that also based on the input file - so if the file never has them in same string, the Markov generator learns not to put them together?

Comment: Actually, right after commenting, it occurs to me I could leave out 1/0 - that seems to cause 90% of my problems in reading computer-generated passwords. :)

Comment: @John C: That's right. The strings generated depend entirely on the contents of the input file.

Answer (score 2):

I like Simon Sapin's version: http://exyr.org/2011/random-pronounceable-passwords/

Answer (score 1):

I guess the project I worked on is applicable. I learned a Markov Model from over 14 million passwords (from the RockYou.com password dump), and created artificial passwords that way. The blog post (and accompanying code) are [here](http://camdp.com/blogs/modeling-password-creation). Some sampled artificial passwords:

- tablester111
- genny0
- mikk92
- lvingree10633769
- bubuzzarap71666
- isamistilloro13020
- dunl0velyiristalecasia4799