# Generating crypto-secure strings for OAuth tokens

Tags: python, oauth, cryptography

I want to generate tokens and keys that are random strings. What is the acceptable method to generate them?

Is generating two UUIDs via standard library functions and concatenating them acceptable?

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Or do you need an OS independent solution?

Answer (score 4):

[os.urandom](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.urandom) provides access to the operating systems random number generator

EDIT: If you are using linux and are very concerned about security, you should use */dev/random/* directly. This call will block until sufficient [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28computing%29#Entropy_in_the_Linux_kernel) is available.

Comment: This can be a good solution _if_ the underlying speudo-random number generator is cryptographically secure.

Comment: See also this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480131/will-python-systemrandom-os-urandom-always-have-enough-entropy-for-good-crypto

Answer (score 0):

Computers (without special hardware) can only generate [*pseudo* random data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-random_number_generator). After a while, all speudo-random number generators will start to repeat themselves. The amount of data it can generate before repeating itself is called the *period*.

A very popular pseudo-random number (also used in Python in the `random` module) generator is the [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister). But it is deemed not suitable for cryptographic purposes, because it is fairly easy to predict the next iteration after observing only a relatively small number of iterates.

See the Wikipedia page on [cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) for a list of algorithms that seem suitable.

Operating systems like FreeBSD, OpenBSD and OS X use the [Yarrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yarrow_algorithm) algorithm for their `urandom` devices. So on those systems using `os.urandom` might be OK, because it is well-regarded as being cryptographically secure.

Of course what you need to use depends to a large degree on how high your requirements are; how secure do you want it to be? In general I would advise you to use published and tested implementations of algorithms. Writing your own implementation is too easy to get wrong.

**Edit:** Computers can *gather* random data by watching e.g. the times at which interrupts arrive. This however does not supply a large amount of random data, and it is therefore often used to seed a PRNG.

Comment: To my understanding the kernel is supposed to gather random data from available sources.

Comment: It's noteworthy that all modern processors contain hardware random sources.